# Pivot with multiple columns

Tags: sql-server

I'm struggling with producing a pivot against at table of transactional data. The table of data I have is as follows:

```
+------------+------------+-----------+------------+
|Date        |Store       |Customer   |Value       |
+------------+------------+-----------+------------+
|01/12/15    |StoreA      |Cust1      |3.80        |
|01/12/15    |StoreB      |Cust2      |2.40        |
|01/12/15    |StoreC      |Cust1      |3.80        |
|02/12/15    |StoreC      |Cust2      |1.50        |
|02/12/15    |StoreA      |Cust2      |1.50        |
|02/12/15    |StoreA      |Cust2      |2.00        |
```

The result I'm trying to get from the pivot is as follows:

```
+-------+-----------+--------+--------+--------+--------+--------+--------+
|Date    |Customer  |StoreA  |StoreB  |StoreC  |StoreAct|StoreBct|StoreCct|
+--------+----------+--------+--------+--------+--------+--------+--------+
|01/12/15|Cust1     |3.80    |        |3.80    |1       |        |1       |
|01/12/15|Cust2     |2.40    |        |        |1       |        |1       |
|02/12/15|Cust2     |3.50    |        |1.50    |2       |        |        |
```

With the value StoreA being the sun of all the transactions on that date and StoreAct being a count of transactions at that store in a day.

After some searching I've tried the following but it doesn't produce the desired  result:

```
SELECT *
FROM (
    SELECT 
        Date, Customer, Value, Store, 1 as TransCount, Store+'ct' as storecount
    FROM SourceTable
) as s
PIVOT
(
    SUM(Value)
    FOR Customer IN (StoreA, StoreB, StoreC)
)AS pvt

PIVOT
(
 SUM(Transcount)
 FOR customer IN (StoreAct, StoreBct, StoreCct)
 )AS pvt
```

All and any help would be much appreciated, thanks

Comment: for one you're saying `For customer in (StoreA, ...` when you should be saying `FOR Store IN (StoreA,... `

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your pivot statements were using `For Customer` instead of the actual column you were trying to pivot.

You should also use the `Count() Over()` window function instead of `1 as TransCount` to get the correct counts.

This can be done dynamically by replacing the sums in the select statement and the column names in the pivot statements pretty easily.

```
SELECT
    [Date],
    Customer,
    SUM(StoreA) StoreA,
    SUM(StoreB) StoreB,
    SUM(StoreC) StoreC,
    SUM(StoreAct) StoreAct,
    SUM(StoreBct) StoreBct,
    SUM(StoreCct) StoreCct
FROM
    (SELECT
        Date,
        Customer,
        Value,
        Store,
        COUNT(*) OVER (PARTITION BY date,customer,store) AS TransCount,
        Store + 'ct' AS storecount
     FROM
        SourceTable
    ) AS s 
PIVOT
( SUM(Value) FOR [Store] IN ([StoreA],[StoreB],[StoreC]) ) AS pvt 
PIVOT
( SUM(Transcount) FOR storecount IN ([StoreAct],[StoreBct],[StoreCct]) ) AS pvt
GROUP BY
    [Date],
    Customer
```

Comment: Thanks for the speedy and correct response, it solved my problem and was cleanly laid out so I can understand how it works. Thanks for your help!